# USB ports stopped working after reboot after a Windows update

Tags: usb, motherboard, windows-11-v22h2

I have this PC:

- Asus ROG strix z270e
- GeForce GTX 1080ti
- Windows 11 Pro

After a Windows update, my USB ports stopped working except one 3.1 USB-A port.

At the back of the motherboard, after trying a lot of things I reinstalled Windows and the problem still persists.

Device managers shows exclamation mark on USB xHCI Compliant Host Controller with error code 10 cannot start.

Even when I plug the front I/O the front USB 3.1 don't work but all USB ports provide power and charges my phone when connected.

It's worth to note that even my BIOS doesn't recognize my mouse and keyboard when plugged into anything but the red USB-C 3.1 port at the back.

Comment: Given that an os reinstall did not fix the problem it does appear to be the motherboard

Comment: @John is there a way to fix it?

Comment: The controller and ports are built in, so no practical way except replacing the motherboard

Comment: Not a great help, but a USB hub can get you working until this is fixed. Its seems unlikely a Windows update could have affected the USB ports at such a low level that BIOS does not see them. You *might* check if there is a BIOS update, but updating it can be risky.

Comment: The fact that keyboard/mouse no longer work in BIOS suggests something else occurred other than a simple windows update - however, given it is an ASUS motherboard, anything is possible - personally, I would power off the computer, remove the power cord, press the power button to drain any last remaining power, reset CMOS, wait 30 seconds, then throw the computer out ... kidding, power back on - to be fair though, this was a process I had to do too many years ago to remember to fix an issue with something I can't even recall - but it's amazing how it worked

Comment: I guess I will throw it out.

Comment: Also not sure if it's related but when I touch my case I feel constant electric feeling, not severe can handle it. Maybe it's related to my usb ports malfunction?

Answer (score -1):

You may try uninstalling the USB 2.0 and 3.0 hubs (similar naming) in device manager. Then restart.

May need to put on Airplane mode / disconnect internet before uninstalling and enable internet after restart.

UPDATE:

Based on comments the reinstall mentioned in original question is from Windows Recovery / Reset option. This will not replace new update packages. You may want to try:

1. Rolling back to previous restore point. (Risky. Also depends on whether it made one right before update).
2. clean installing Windows with USB boot stick using using media creation tool [here](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11). This deletes all data both on USB & PC (depending on which partitions you select during install) hence take full backup beforehand on external storage to avoid losing your data.

Comment: Since the  os was reinstalled this likely will not change anything

Comment: I am curious how the reinstall was done. Was it from inside Windows or clean install via USB. Because doing from inside Reset option may not have replaced the latest updates.

Comment: @ShubhamDeshmukhit was from inside windows using the startup recovery

Comment: I tried uninstalling the controllers and hub and restarting to no avail

Comment: @RL.AdmiralX you may try clean installing windows via USB boot stick. Make one using media creation tool [here](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11). Take full backup beforehand on external storage to avoid losing your data.

Comment: Clean installed windows and now it's still persists. No USB ports working and xhci still cannot start and code 10

Comment: @RL.AdmiralX That means hardware failure. That it coincided with the windows update is probably just that, a coincidence.